# Objective C button in Swift App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, swift, uibutton

I am rewriting one of my apps in Swift but I would like to use the Objective C code for that one button. Is this possible and if so how would I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is [certainly possible](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Just bring over your .m and .h file, and add the header to your bridging header.

Comment: The code for the button is currently in the ViewController.m in the old project. Is it possible to use the code as an extension of the ViewController.swift in the new project.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't think you can mix objective-c and swift within the same file.  You'll have to refactor the objective-c code you want to use into its own object and stand-alone file.